# Can we take a const ref of a substring?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdstring, flyweight-pattern

I have a class, which contains a string as a private member. The class has public member functions which all return a const ref to a std::wstring.

All of the const-ref strings being returned are substrings of the private member.

I could store each substring as members, then return const refs to those members, but this is not optimal as it duplicates memory.

Assume that I do store enough memory to know the start and end index of each substring.

How do I implement the above class without copying any of the member string?

Comment: may be boost::string_ref with help you for your task

Comment: Duplicate? [How can I pass a substring by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490246/how-can-i-pass-a-substring-by-reference). What is suggested here is passing an iterator, or treating it like a char*.

Comment: return `std::string_view` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view instead?

Comment: `string` or `wstring`? Are you using both, or is that a typo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not legal, and it is not going to save you anything.  [`std::string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) returns by value.  That means it makes a copy of the data from the class member no matter how you return it.  When you return a reference to that, you are returning a reference to a temporary local object.  the const reference lifetime extensions rules wont work here and what you are left with at the call site is a dangling reference.

What you can do though is just return by value.  By default this will cause a move, and the compiler can quite easily optimize this away by eliding the temporary construction directly into the object in the call site.

Another option is to have a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) member, and return sub strings from that.  Doing that only costs you the copying of a pointer and a integer, so it will be quite fast.